# Hanging faux wood blinds- screw broken. Is there a tough screw I can use for a wall stud?

Tags: drywall, walls, windows, screws, screwdriver

Job= I was trying to hang up some new faux wood 2" slat blinds. It's a double sized window, so I bought 2 blinds. I needed to install 4 brackets, with 2  in the center. I predrilled the holes as the directions suggested, with a 1/16" drill bit.

Problem= When I tried to install one of the center brackets, I noticed that my screw had difficulty going in. I figured I had hit a stud in the wall. But I figured that my screw should be tough enough to handle it. It broke off while I was screwing it with my Phillips. I know that the answer should be just to move my bracket away from the stud, but the stud is right where the center of both of my blind ends meet.

Question= What kind of screw should I get that will be tough enough to go into the wood without breaking off? It needs to be a small screw, the kind of size that will fit in a blind bracket. (the directions didnt indicate to me what the size of the screw was). I just want to know what kind of screw to get. I have heard of titanium screws- are those especially tough and something I should consider? Or do they make screws especially for studs?

I will be going to Lowe's tomorrow. I didnt want to have to ask them because the last time I asked them a question they didnt know the answer, so I am asking everyone here. Thanks, Julie

Edit: I tried another screw 1 inch away from where the other screw broke, and that screw broke also. I am going to have to 1) Try to drill more deeply and see if that helps, 2) Buy special wood screws. I'll look for the  most expensive wood screws. 3) It might be a metal plate that I cant see. If that is the case, I will return the 2 blinds and purchase a double wide blind. Thanks everyone for your advice! I looking for a 1 1/4 inch screw.

Comment: What is the width/length of these blinds? Most screws would not break due to drilling into a stud. It may have just been faulty and had a weak spot. Depending on length/width of blinds you may not even need center support (despite what instructions may say). I have installed many without and they have been fine

Comment: @LBJ33 She needs the center support because **bought 2 blinds**. It is 2 "regular" instead of 1 "double-wide". So the support is needed.

Comment: The screws that come with blinds are often the cheapest imported crap available. I can't tell you how many such screws I've twisted off *by hand*.  I'd replace them with screws from a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: @isherwood - is absolutely correct. Even the generic "blister pack" screws from Lowes, Homedepot, etc. are pretty crappy. Buy name brand screws if you can. They'll be more expensive, but well worth the extra price.

Answer (score 1):

Highly resinous pine studs can get very hard with age. You should drill the pilot hole the full depth that the screw will go into the stud then a little past that.

Often the diameter of the pilot hole must be increased over the recommended. The drill you used (1/16") is very small. When you get your new screws you will probably need to use a 1/8" bit or even 3/16". The drill diameter should ideally be very slightly larger than the solid shaft of the screw but obviously smaller than the extent of the threads so the threads bite solidly.

One way to do this is of course to use a larger diameter drill bit,  but often just repeatedly moving the drill in and out while drilling enlarges the hole enough to allow much easier driving of the screw.

Apply wax or other lubricant to the screw threads before insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You said you pre-drilled but then said you thought you hit a stud with the screw?

Nope not if you pre-drilled.

If you did that properly and drilled all the way into what the depth of your screw would be, you would have drilled into that stud and the screw would go in just fine. The drill bit when you backed it out, you should have seen the pine wood on the bit flute : if it went into a stud.

Perhaps you did not drill deep enough or maybe there is a metal protective plate - protecting pipes or wires. Further your drill bit could be a size to small for the screws.

**Wood Screws are what you want** - standard wood screws are fine - they go through studs just fine - pine is a VERY soft wood (of course that is relative - if some one hit me with one I probably would say it was hard enough).

**No there are no special screws just for studs.**

When was your home built and did they use steel studs to build it ?

Comment: He also could have hit a knot - knots in dimensional lumber can be very hard... but again, predrilling is key to preventing breaking. A hardened deck screw could help too, in case the OP used a drywall or regular brass or steel wood screw.

Comment: @aaron agreed - predilling is really the key - I try to pre-drill in most applications unless I see my pine and don't need to waste time - especially that stuff from new zealand - it is so soft it is like balsa wood.

Comment: Edit: I tried another screw 1 inch away from where the other screw broke, and that screw broke also. I am going to have to 1) Try to drill more deeply and see if that helps, 2) Buy special wood screws. I'll look for the  most expensive wood screws. 3) It might be a metal plate that I cant see. If that is the case, I will return the 2 blinds and purchase a double wide blind. Thanks everyone for your advice!

Comment: waxing screws before inserting can help a little too - it lubricates them going in.

Comment: @OwlJulie Get a rare earth magnet - run it across the area where you are drilling and see if it sticks - that will tell you if there is a plate back there. Also when drilling look at the tip of the drill bit when you pull it back out - look for metal particulates, brick particulates or wood . Here is something that might interest you https://uniquehunters.com/walabot-gives-x-ray-vision-see-behind-walls-using-smartphone/

Answer (score 0):

Screws are normally hardened although wood screw less likely than deck and sheet metal screws. Some producers may not have much quality control on heat-treatment so it may have been too hard an brittle. No big deal , just get a different screw and be sure to drill pilot holes . Stainless steel deck screws are a different story ,they are relatively soft and require correct pilot holes.